# Simple environment mapping in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to get a simple environment mapping object without creating a cubemap like most of the three.js demos.
If I enter in the threejs editor (http://threejs.org/editor/) I create a simple icosa sphere, add MeshLamberMaterial and just change the envmap texture it works as expected.
But If I try to recreate the same steps in a simple material I just get black sphere.
Could anyone tell me what I'm missing where?

```
var materialSphere1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    envMap: map,
    reflectivity: 1.0
} );
```

Here the complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/tK2BL/1/

Comment: Since it is not supported in three.js r.62, a work-around is to use `ShaderMaterial` and write your own shader.

Comment: @WestLangley  Why is it that in the editor it at least shows a "reflection" (i know it is pretty wrong, but still) and using a meshLambert in the fiddle with an ordinary texture in envMap-slot does not work at all and displays a black object?

Comment: @GuyGood I can't comment on the editor. Regarding the fiddle, the `envMap` when using `WebGLRenderer` must be a cubemap. three.js r.62.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. We still haven't implemented spherical reflection mapping in `WebGLRenderer`...